# Unwind not going to the right viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, unwind-segue

I am trying to use an unwind segue to logout from my app.

Here is my view hierarchy:

`MainVC->(show)->ConnectionVC->(show)->HomeTabBarVC->SettingsVC (4th tab of the HomeTabBarVC containing a tableview)`

MainVC, ConnectionVC and HomeTabBarVC are in three different Storyboards.

When pressing the "Disconnect" row of `SettingsVC`, I want to unwind to `MainVC`.

I already tried to follow this:

[What are unwind segues and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and

[Unwind segue and nav button items not triggering after tab bar controller added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659845/unwind-segue-and-nav-button-items-not-triggering-after-tab-bar-controller-added)

The `unwindToThisViewController` function (which I put in `MainVC`) from the tutorial is triggered but the only thing that happens is going back to the first tab of `HomeTabBarVC`.

I tried to execute this action in `SettingsVC` in two ways:

```
(self.tabBarController! as! HomeTabBarVC).performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainVC", sender: self)
```

and

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainVC", sender: self)
```

Neither are working...

Any toughts?

Comment: Where did you put the `self.performSegue(...)` line of code? That should work fine, assuming you properly created and named the segue...

Comment: In tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath). I check the the row corresponds to Disconnect

Comment: OK - so... you added your "unwind" function to `MainVC` class code... you dragged from the little "Class" icon to the "Exit" icon at the top of `HomeTabBarVC` in Interface Builder, and selected your unwind function from the popup... then you selected that segue in Document Outline, and gave it the "unwindToMainVC" identifier? And you have a `print()` or something in your unwind func so you know it's being called?

Comment: By the way... do a string search in your project for your unwind function name. Do you happen to have it defined in more than one view controller?

Comment: Yes DongMag I did all the steps, I could even see the print.. But now I fixed my problem I'll post the answer

Comment: *sigh* ... I see you are new to Stack Overflow... In the future, please include all relevant information ***including error and/or warning messages*** in your original post. Helps avoid wasting other people's time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using unwind segues. Just use `popToRootViewController`:

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Hello the4kman and thanks for your quick answer !
I am not using a UINavigationController though..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : after seeing that I had the "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged " warning, I created a Delegate to execute the segue in my HomeTabBarVC and it works fine! Thanks everyone for your help!!